# UITable , Section con Imagen dinamicamente Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Tengo la siguiente tabla que hasta el momento se ve asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se ve aqui son los titulos de las secciones , con el efecto acordeon , lo que me gustaria es poder ponerle una imagen al lado de cada titulo , para tener un efecto como este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigando vi que puedo dinamicamente en el metodo

```
viewForHeaderInSection
```

agregarle esta imagen mi codigo hasta ahora es

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.addBottomBorder(Utils.Color.COLOR_SEPARACIONES, height: 2.5, separation: 0)
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnHeader(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.tag = section
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    let label : UILabel = UILabel()
    label.text = sectionTitles[section]
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 5, width: 200, height: 30)
    label.textColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_2B5034
    view.addSubview(label)

    return view
}
```

No estoy seguro de como puedo crear una imagen dinamicamente y agregarle las contrains para que quede centrado con respecto al label , desde ya gracias , utilizo swift 4

Comment: ¿De donde obtienes la imagen dinámica? ¿De una URL? ¿De un recurso? La respuesta completa depende de donde obtengas la imagen...

Comment: La Imagen la tendre en mis assets , me explique mal disculpa Marcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que crear un `UIImageView` y agregarlo como `subview` de la variable `view`.

En el método `func tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` tienes que agregar:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)) // el frame seguramente varíe...
imageView.image = UIImage(...) // ver desde donde se obtiene la imagen
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: Con respecto a la Label como podria agregarle contrain para que quede centrado? , se puede lograr este efecto? , la imagen estara en mis assets

Comment: Me puse a jugar con las x y las y de los CGReact y los deje alineados nose si es lo mas performante o no , pero respecto a la pregunta la respuesta fue exitosa muchas gracias @Marcos